# How to replace or update the string instances of a DataFrame from predefined substrings list using Regular Expression in Python

Tags: python, pandas, replace, substring

DataFrame instances are of mixed alphanumeric string type. But all the instances in the DataFrame contain only one common substring from the three strings namely **normal, background, botnet**. I want to replace all the instances of the dataframe to these 3 instances so that dataframe type would become the categorical.

```
OriginalDF                                  ConvertedDF
To-background flow udp flows                background
To-botnet flow tcp syn packet               botnet
To-normal flow tcp syn packet               normal
To-normal flow tcp flows                    normal
To-botnet flow ack connection established   botnet
To- normal flow tcp flows                   normal
To-background flow tcp flows                background
```

I have tried using an iterative approach and this works fine.

```
   for i in range(cat_data.shape[0]):

    if( "Background" in cat_data.Label[i]):
        cat_data.Label[i] = "Background"
    elif( "Normal" in cat_data.Label[i]):
        cat_data.Label[i] = "Normal"
    else:
        cat_data.Label[i] = "Botnet"
```

Is their any standard or customized way of doing such task using Regular Expression that does the job using only one or two statements, not traditional iterative way?

Comment: Can you provide your data in text format so that i can use it to check whether i can come up with something more optimal?

Comment: @nitin3685 before making any post as duplicate, please explain why it is being as duplicate. Give an answer first, then mark it as duplicte. Don't do blindly. Here in this questions, i clearly said that i have a list of substrings. I have to use replace method, not selection or search to extract that substrings.

Comment: @nitin3685 actually, Datasets are huge in size. You can make a dataframe consisting data from the  figure in the questions and use substring(more than one) for filtering using RE

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat. Please provide the picture as text. I can't copy the picture into my editor.

Comment: Please elaborate on "not working". That statement is meaningless without further explanation.

Comment: @nitin3685, I made the picture only for understanding the better scenarios of my questions. This is not the actual one. But if you understood the questions, you can easily make a dataframe like these data. Here is a sketch: 
Original DataFrame  Converted DataFrame
To-background flow udp flows              background
To-normal flow tcp ack packet flows normal
To-botnet flow tcp syn packet              botnet
To- normal flow tcp flows                      normal
To- botnet flow ack connection botnet
To- normal flow tcp flows              normal
To- background flow tcp flows  background

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat. It would be very helpful if you replaced the image with the contents of your comment. Questions should never refer to your full data. They must contain minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat: I asked for the sample data because it is easier to work with on out system. I don't need the entire dataset. And it is quite some work to look at the image and type it out.

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat : I marked it as duplicate because I felt search the sub-string and creating a new column would  be simple based on link. Of course i would have tried to provide the code for it, if i has the data in text format.

Comment: @nitin3685 thanks for your response. Actually, I am new in ML and if anything surely looks easy make an explanation first, then you duplicate, do whatever you wish. But if you comment, it will be helpful as a newbie like me to explore better.

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat. While your update is somewhat helpful, you are still ignoring the request to post sample data in the question. The image should be replaced with the equivalent sample. You should not require people to go offsite to help you, and a complete dataset is not necessary. What's in the picture is fine, but please make it usable.

Comment: @sofiullahsaikat I have not down voted your question. I didn't know you were still waiting for an answer , as i did not see any comments on Mad physicist answer. I just assumed you had found your answer with his suggestion. I wasn't being unfriendly. I will post my answer when i login tomorrow.

Comment: @nitin3685 I am very sorry that I shouldn't forced you to solve. Anyway, you can see and use the editable sample dataset for the solution updated in post(link) and also here is also a shareable link for you.....
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RK4NlwkHQnWhO2WVk0GPw5JDjVr1-dh2/view?usp=sharing
Again, thank you for being kind. I am not forcing you to solve but I am looking for the solution .

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat : I have removed the duplicate tag since you are being very specific that you want to use replace and no for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the solution from @Mad Physicist, I have other solutions.
test.csv container the following

```
Original_DataFrame
To-background flow udp flows 
To-normal flow tcp ack packet flows
To-botnet flow tcp syn packet 
To- normal flow tcp flows
To- botnet flow ack connection
To- normal flow tcp flows
To- background flow tcp flows
```

**Solution 1:**
Using List comprehension.
I am using a convert function to return the required string.
I have put this solution to demonstrate that there are various ways to do it. 
Pick the one most suitable for you.

```
import pandas as pd

def convert_string(string):
    if 'background' in string:
        return 'background'
    elif 'normal' in string:
        return 'normal'
    elif 'botnet' in string:
        return 'botnet'
    else :
        return 'Nan'

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['New_DataFrame'] =  [ convert_string(string) for string in df['Original_DataFrame']]
print(df)
```

Solution 2: Using pandas idioms. if-then with `.loc`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df['New_DataFrame'] = "XXX"
df.loc[df.Original_DataFrame.str.contains('normal'), 'New_DataFrame'] = 'normal'
df.loc[df.Original_DataFrame.str.contains('botnet'), 'New_DataFrame'] = 'botnet'
df.loc[df.Original_DataFrame.str.contains('background'), 'New_DataFrame'] = 'background'
```

Comment: Second solution is awesome as I expected like that. Thanks a ton for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with regex, you can use capture groups to extract the text you want:

```
df['data'].str.replace('.*(normal|background|botnet).*', '\\1')
```

A back reference like `\1` in the replacement string allows you to refer to the contents of a capture group.

Comment: Sir, This statement showed meTypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'.

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat. Please go through the comments very carefully and update your question.

Comment: I think the stated question(updated) have all the clearifications needed to understand the problem. If you found any solutions, then please let me know the approach. Thanks.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have edited your answer with input and output . Can you also please add what '\\1' does , for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @nitin3685. Please do not edit code in other people's work. Making reasonable suggestions through comments is fine. I've added a sentence to explain `\\1`, but I would expect someone to look at the docs if they wanted to know more. After all, this will be a good starting point for many, but I doubt it will fit everyone's use-case exactly.

Comment: @MadPhysicist : Apologies!! Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Thanks people for being so nice. I am really greatful to you. Seeing the easy solutions which I thought as tough, myself felt really foolish.

Comment: @SofiUllahSaikat. Thanks for taking the time to update your question. I've reversed my vote now. It's good etiquette to select an answer that works for you by clicking on the check mark next to it so that your question will no longer be marked as unanswered. I'm glad you enjoyed your experience here. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

Use apply function:
Take a look at this [Remove opening and closing parenthesis with word in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680191/remove-opening-and-closing-parenthesis-with-word-in-pandas/58680226#58680226)

It's just pseudo code

```
def f(x):
    apply regex like re.findall(exp,x)
    nested if else
    check if val == value 1:
         return something
    other if else condition

df['label'] = df['label'].apply(f)
```

Comment: I think your iterative methods would work in this case. But this is an iterative approach, loops every row of the column. Do you provide any suggestions/infos regarding using replace function in this case?